# Shibboleth bypass for IP range

Tags: web-services, shibboleth

I have Shibboleth configured on an IIS server and am using it protect a .NET application.

I need authenticated access for users accessing the application over the web and for that Shibboleth is working fine.

The application also hosts web services which need to be accessed by other applications in the same server and for that working with Shibboleth is a challenge since web service clients cannot deal with the log in page.

Is it possible to configure Shibboleth to ignore requests coming from the same server for example by checking the IP address?

Answer (score 1):

It won't directly answer your question, but I can share a workaround I found and hope it can help with your problem too.

Define another website in IIS pointing to the same folder as the initial one, and make it only respond to a different domain (like something.local). Then in IP Address and Domain Restrictions, make sure only 127.0.0.1 is allowed to access it.

In C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc open the file "hosts" in Notepad (running with Administrator privileges). Add the line "127.0.0.1 something.local" (no quotes; make sure the domain is the same one you defined before)

Now, make the webservices call the application by the new domain.

Comment: This will launch a second instance of your web application if you're running it out of process so this is probably not viable in such cases...